# Git heroku error: on push heroku

Tags: facebook, git, heroku, github

I have been developing a facebook app for a while, and now I want to change all the files, except I get this error when trying to git push heroku:

```
C:\Users\amando96\deep-window-4782>git push heroku
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 2.78 KiB, done.
Total 11 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:deep-window-4782.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:deep-window-4782.git'

C:\Users\amando96\deep-window-4782>
```

And it doesn't update the git repository, and thus the app isn't updated either.

What am I missing?

thanks.

Comment: What language are you developing in? Is your `Procfile` up-to-date with your code changes?

Comment: It's just static HTML and the scripting is just client side javascript.

Never had a procfile, seemed to not need one earlier, I've updated this countless times before, only got the error when I changed all the files, keeping AppInfo and the like, though.

Comment: Ah, ok. Never had experience deploying static sites to Heroku. The obvious answer is to go through your changes step by step and find and find out what specific change made things break. `git bisect` can be helpful here if your commits are granular enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this may have worked for you before - it shouldn't have.

For an easy way to host static websites on the Cedar stack, there's nice 'trick' for using their PHP buildpack to get a vanilla Apache server, and then turn off PHP support.

See http://kennethreitz.com/static-sites-on-heroku-cedar.html

Comment: It wasn't static at first, I had a few AJAX calls to PHP pages as well as PHP authentication, but decided to remove unnecessary things and do all the scripting client side + a feed dialogue at the end, it's not sensitive info, so it doesn't really matter.

Added an index.php file that just includes the HTML I want to output, and it worked.